# Powershell Script to read from a txt file with a list of URls and its properties and update sharepoint

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a script to extract some urls and other metadata from the below format and upload to sharepoint and update the file properties.

My txt file contains

20/01/2023 8:30:01 AM  12456 https://www.google.com/someURL.docx

22/01/2023 8:30:01 AM  12456 https://www.amazon.com/test.pdf

Output

The above url(https://www.google.com/someURL.docx) files to be downloaded to a sharepoint library and
the date (20/01/2023 8:30:01 AM) and the ID (12456) to be updated in a sharepoint document library properties

Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Below is my code to download the files to sharepoint and it worked perfectly with the text file contains only URLS like below

**text file contents**
https://www.google.com/someURL.docx
https://www.amazon.com/test.pdf

```
$path1 = "C:\Users\Export Test\"
Foreach ($link in $links)
{
$filename = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($link).GetResponse()
$basename = Split-Path($filename.ResponseUri.OriginalString) -leaf
$filename.Close()
$output = Join-Path $path1 $basename
Invoke-WebRequest -URI $filename.ResponseUri -Outfile $output
}
```

This works perfectly with only URLS in the text file but i need the above details from the txt file to be updated in sharepoint when the file is downloaded.

Comment: Are those pipe symbols `|` actually part of the file or dit you attempt to post it as table? Please open the file in notepad, copy a  few lines from the top so we can see how the data is delimited

Comment: pipe symbols are not in the file it came as when i posted as table. In my txt file it is space. THe first line is date number URL

Comment: Then please [edit] the question and post exactly as-is

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us the **exact** first couple of lines of your input file, so chances are it is a valid CSV file using some delimiter character you did not type in the post..

Therefore, **IF** that is the real content of your file, and the fields are separated sometimes by a single and sometimes by a double space,
and where the url is always the last part of the line, you can get a list of links from it using:

```
$links = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\blah.txt' | 
         ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '\s+')[-1].Trim() } |  # split on whitespace(s) and return the last element
         Where-Object { $_ -match '^https?://' }            # capture only the strings that start with http:// or https://
```

If the fields are separated by TAB characters instead, you could use Import-Csv:

```
$links = (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\blah.txt' -Header Date, ID, Url -Delimiter "`t").Url
```

Comment: Thanks Theo for your assistance. How do we update a sharepoint library by downloading the files from the URL of the txt file and update the metadata such as Date and ID.

Comment: all good. i got it working in a different method. thanks for your assistance